# Trying to load canvas image from file directory

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I found this jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/t7mv6/86/ that works exactly like I need.  Have been searching for examples and studied several online html5 canvas tutorials.  I am trying to load several images selected from many in a directory to one html5 canvas.
I wrote this attempt to  use the jsfiddle:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <HEAD>
 <script type="text/javascript">
var input = document.getElementById('input');

input.addEventListener('click', handleFiles);
var i=0;
function handleFiles(e) {alert("here");

    var ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');

    var img = new Image;
    alert("hello");
    img.src = URL.createObjectURL(e.target.files[0]);
    img.onload = function() {
        ctx.drawImage(img, 20,20);
        alert('the image is drawn');

    }
}
  </script>

  </head>
  <Body >

<h1>Test</h1>
<input type="file" id="input"/>
<canvas width="800" height="500" id="canvas"/>

</body>
</html>
```

The above will not work on my chrome or firefox.
It seems to display initial page correctly but the image does not display in the canvas.

I think I may have a security problem or need to wrap it with an onload.
Don't really understand syntax for the onload function.
js console indicates no errors.

Any help appreciated!

Tim

Comment: Just add the `onload` listener first before setting `src` because setting `src` triggers `onload`

Comment: @EdwinReynoso, It's a good precaution to put `onload` before `src` but in practice it's rare for the image to finish loading asynchronously before the `image.onload` line is read.

Comment: Idk where you would think that's rare? it all depends how long the image takes because the image is loaded asynchronously, that's how you guarantee `onload` to fire, yea if the image is big and takes a while the onload event is read before image is loaded.

Comment: It's `onload` so yea it's once the image actually loads, so again if it takes a while then yea. But adding `onload` guarantees it

Comment: Thanks for code example !!  I will play around with that.

Comment: Thanks for code example markE.  "Multiples" looks like what I needed. Having problems entering these comments!! Return key is tricky!!  Will play around with the example and research the other comments. Thanks to all.  My images are all scaled to about 80x100 px and I would like for them to display full scale(1:1) on canvas.  timathis

Answer (score 1):

You can select multiple images by adding the `multiple` attribute to your `input`.

```
<input type="file" multiple id="input"/>
```

**Here's example code an a Demo on how to show your multiple images as thumbnails on a single canvas.**

```js
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
var cw=canvas.width;
var ch=canvas.height;

var input = document.getElementById('input');
input.addEventListener('change', handleFiles);

function handleFiles(e) {
  //    var images=[];
  var files=e.target.files;
  for(var i=0;i<files.length;i++){
    var img=new Image;
    img.x=i*100;
    img.onload=function(){
      ctx.drawImage(this,this.x,0,80,this.height*(80/this.width));
    }
    img.src=URL.createObjectURL(files[i]);
  }
}
```

```css
body{ background-color: ivory; }
#canvas{border:1px solid red;}
```

```html
<input type="file" multiple id="input"/>
<br>
<canvas id="canvas" width=400 height=300></canvas>
```